# Neo4j: Convenient Backend for Network Navigation, Editing and Search

Tags: neo4j

I'm a sociology PhD student and I'm trying to use Neo4j to manually build the social network of the political elite in a given country. I say "manually" because I will need to input all the data manually as I come across it in my readings.

For this I would need an interface that allows me to navigate the network, as well as search and edit my database conveniently. Crucially, that would include the capacity to search for node and relationship attributes, and edit the database in real time when in graph visualization mode.

It looks like the default Neo4j admin dashboard only allows you to search by node and relationship numbers, and doesn't allow the editing of the database when in graph visualization mode. Am I right? If so, is there an alternative interface that will allow me to do this? I looked into Neoeclipse but I'm not sure it's the right tool for the job. (I also haven't been able to properly load my database on it)

Thanks in advance for the help!

JB

Answer (score 1):

Which version are you looking at? Neo4j 2.0 is a really convenient UI for what you want to do.

You can easily find by property:

```
MATCH (user:User {name="Peter"}) return user
```

or

```
MATCH (user:User {name="Peter"})-[:KNOWS]->(other) return user,other
```

And you can store these queries as favorites so you don't have to type them more than once.

And you can explore the graph by double clicking nodes.

For the visualization, if you click once on each node you can see its properties and also configure which property is shown in the graph.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm using Neo4j 2.0.I gave it a try. The problem is that this browser interface doesn't actually allow me to edit the database -- I have to go to the webadmin interface to change node and relationship attributes... any way around that?

Comment: I just discovered Keylines and it's exactly the kind of interface I'm looking for. Is there an open source alternative?